# removing copies from a list

Tags: python

For context: Users can add items to a list. I want to remove all identical submissions. Is there a more efficient way to do this:?

```
def removeCopies(self):
    i = 0
    while i != self.size:
        number = self.contents.count(self.contents[i])
        if number != 1:
            for j in range(1, number):
                self.delete(self.contents.index(self.contents[i], i + 1))
        i += 1
```

Comment: Why not use a set to begin with?

Comment: to remove duplicates and preserve order:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-whilst-preserving-order

Answer (score 3):

The most efficient way I can think of to delete duplicates is

```
self.contents = list(set(self.contents))
```

This will not preserve the order of your items, but at least you won't end up with an O(n<sup>3</sup>) algorithm.

An even better solution would be to make `self.contents` a `set` to begin with, so users can not enter duplicates at all, if you have the option to do that.